# How to check attachment is encrypted or not in Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-5.1, shrine

I want to give a validation error message if user tries to upload encrypted file in a Ruby on Rails Application. I'm using a Shrine gem for attachment. How i can do it - any idea ?

I'm using: Rails 5.1.6, ruby 2.4.2p198, shrine 2.9.0.

---

This is my initializer

```
require 'shrine'

Shrine.plugin :activerecord
Shrine.plugin :cached_attachment_data # for forms
Shrine.plugin :determine_mime_type
Shrine.plugin :backgrounding
Shrine.plugin :delete_promoted

Shrine::Attacher.promote { |data| PromoteJob.perform_async(data) }
Shrine::Attacher.delete { |data| DeleteJob.perform_async(data) }
```

This uploader

```
class DocumentUploader < Shrine
  plugin :validation_helpers
  plugin :pretty_location

  plugin :processing
  plugin :versions

 process(:store) do |io, context|
    original = io.download
    out_file = Tempfile.new(["pdfsigned~", '.pdf'])
    SignPdf.sign_pdf!(original, io.original_filename, out_file, 
    context[:record], context[:record].creator_company, :uploaded, {} , false)
   { original: io, stamped: out_file }
 end

 Attacher.validate do
   validate_mime_type_inclusion ['application/pdf']
end
```

end

when i create document. it doesnt check and accepts the encrypted file

Comment: A file is a stream of bytes. An encrypted file is a stream of bytes. You need to come up with criteria for telling two bytestreams apart, because from technical point of view, there's no difference. How do you, as a human, tell if a file is "valid", encrypted, corrupted or just random garbage?

Answer (score 0):

Whitelisting allowed MIME types detected by the `determine_mime_type` Shrine plugin should automatically reject encrypted files. Encrypting a file changes its content, including the "magic bytes" which utilities like the `file` command use to determine the MIME type of the file.

So if an encrypted file is uploaded, the `file` command (used by default in `determine_mime_type` Shrine plugin) should return the generic `application/octet-stream` MIME type, and fail the whitelist.

To implement this, first load the plugins in your initializer:

```
Shrine.plugin :determine_mime_type
Shrine.plugin :validation_helpers
```

Then add `validate_mime_type_inclusion` checks in your uploader, for example:

```
# image_uploader.rb
class ImageUploader < Shrine
  Attacher.validate do
    validate_mime_type_inclusion %W[image/jpeg image/png image/webp]
  end
end

# video_uploader.rb
class VideoUploader < Shrine
  Attacher.validate do
    validate_mime_type_inclusion %W[video/mpeg video/mp4]
  end
end
```

Comment: I've already included the required plugins but it doesnt seem to be working for me.

Comment: It works for me, here is an example showing the desired behaviour: https://github.com/shrinerb/shrine/issues/283#issuecomment-405290250 (just posting for reference)